# jquery detecting file change and displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logfile

I have a text file that is modified by different python scripts, and I want to create a jquery function that detects each change in that file and to display that change in an initially empty html div

```
<div id="logtext"> </div>
```

using

```
document.getElementById('logtext').innerHTML= new_content_of_the_file;
```

( something similar to displaying a logfile )
how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use HTML like this:

```
var content = data_from_python;
$("#logtext").html(content);
```

The difference between HTML and `append()` function is that HTML replaces the content of your `div`. It's the equivalent of `innerHTML` while `append` just adds content to the end of an element.

Here is a reference on this topic:
[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#logtext').append('<p>' + resultMessage + '</p>');
```

Comment: Since it looks like he is appending JSON data, I would use `<pre>` tags for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use append or html like this:

```
$("#logtext").append("to do");
```